# How to use a Android button XML file programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I have been using a few images for buttons (the XML below) - but a part of my project I have needed to create a button programmatically, which is not formatted like this others (which I would like it to be).

**Buttonshape.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonpressed" />
</selector>
```

My code that creates a button

```
            Button newBut;     
            newBut = new Button(this);
            newBut.setText("SOME TEXT");
            newBut.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));
            newBut.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            newBut.setSingleLine();
            newBut.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(50);
            newBut.setSelected(true);
```

This is the code from a Activity with the formatted buttons

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tabdemo.Tab1Activity"
    android:background="#00547d"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"

            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"   
         />




    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way of using **android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"** programatically

Comment: do you want set button background programatically?

Comment: The java code above creates a standard button, but all other buttons are images that use Buttonshape.xml. I want the button I created programaticly to also use Buttonshape.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.buttonshape));
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I have been searching for the answer for a while now. Cheers. ;)